# Respondi uma questão e tempos depois encontrei uma solução melhor. Como fazer?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, edição

Há alguns dias [respondi uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/585/como-corrigir-url-de-requisicao-post-utilizando-rest-no-extjs-4).
Hoje encontrei por acaso uma solução melhor que a minha em outro fórum.

Acho importantíssimo incluir essa nova solução.

Qual regra podemos adotar em casos como esse?
Em outras palavras, quando um usuário responder a uma questão e algum tempo depois ele mesmo encontrar uma solução melhor, como ele pode adicionar essa nova solução a questão?

Algumas observações para pensarmos em casos distintos:

1. A solução anterior foi dada pelo próprio usuário que quer sugerir uma nova;
2. A solução proposta anteriormente estava incorreta (e ninguém havia percebido);
3. A solução proposta anteriormente auxiliou parcialmente;
4. A solução proposta anteriormente resolveu o problema levantado na questão, porém a nova traz uma abordagem melhor;
5. Em conjunto com as opções anteriores, a resposta pode ter sido ou não marcada como certa.

Answer (score 8):

1. Você deve postar a nova com certeza.
2. Se está incorreta, você pode só alertar para o fato (em alguns casos pode ser útil deixar para orientar), ou melhor ainda, remover a resposta
3. Provavelmente é melhor deixar e alertar que a outra é melhor
4. O mesmo
5. O ideal é aceitar a melhor resposta

Comment: Concordo, mas é bom deixar claro que não é necessário **literalmente** se remover uma resposta ao postar outra - basta editar a já existente. Em alguns casos (resposta melhor por exemplo) também não é necessário manter a antiga no corpo do texto, basta mencionar que ela existe em arquivo (como fiz [nessa resposta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/423/como-calcular-o-digestvalue-do-xml/433#433) por exemplo) - uma vez que o histórico de revisões pode ser acessado por quem quiser mais detalhes.

Comment: @mgibsonbr O único problema que vejo nisso é que as pessoas votaram em uma resposta que não está mais lá. O voto permanece para algo que não foi votado. Claro que é pouco provável que tenha algum problema, mas é possível que a pessoa que votou na resposta anterior não votaria na nova.

Comment: Ok, mas esse é um problema bem mais geral. Veja por exemplo quando alguém vota contrário em um post, o autor melhora o post e os usuários não voltam para reavaliá-lo: no final você fica com um post bom, mas cheio de votos negativos. O "legado" de um post não pode ser apagado, e isso cria problemas nas duas direções, e em uma variedade de cenários. Não é algo com o qual eu me preocuparia, mas isso é somente minha opinião.

Comment: Gostei da sugestão, @bigown. O que ainda não tenho claro é se devemos incluir uma nova resposta ou editar a resposta já existente. No caso que citei na minha questão vou editar minha resposta.