# O que fazer quando após aceitar uma resposta e depois surge uma bem melhor?

Tags: debate, suporte

Deparei-me com uma situação complicada hoje. Após fazer uma [questão](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161821/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-on-a-file-using-vi?noredirect=1#comment264926_161821)(noutro site) surgiu depois uma resposta que resolveu o meu problema.

Momentos depois surgiu uma mais simples e "eficiente" e resolve o mesmo problema. Nota que além de ser um método mais simples, a resposta foi dada com maior clareza que aquela que já havia aceite.

Será correto "desaceitar" a primeira resposta e aceitar a nova?

Nota:

Creio que não seja uma duplicata com [esta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/respondi-uma-quest%C3%A3o-e-tempos-depois-encontrei-uma-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-melhor-como-fazer), contudo peço que analisem.

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/494/91)

Answer (score 12):

**Sim, isso é absolutamente correto.** Você deve marcar como aceita a resposta que melhor responde ao seu problema. Se ela surgiu mais tarde, tudo bem trocar a aceitação.

Mesmo assim, sempre recomendo calma para aceitar uma resposta. Ao marcar uma resposta como aceita, a chance de novas respostas surgirem diminui. É bom esperar a pergunta "esfriar" um pouco antes de marcar a resposta aceita.

Comment: Pois é, eu observei que lá no site, eles obrigam esperam 10 minutos se não me engano. Aqui também neh?

Comment: Você é quem decide quanto esperar, depois do tempo mínimo que o sistema te impõe. Eu costumo esperar algumas horas, a não ser que ache que não tem muita chance de aparecerem mais respostas.

Comment: Respondeu "esfriar" p/ o @Cold, você é um fanfarrão :D Eu raramente espero menos que dias.

Comment: OK, passarei a espera. Mas poderá haver uma situação de "aflição" e aparece uma resposta que resolveu o teu problema, esperar pode ser estranho  principalmente quando vôce já agradeceu com comentários, kkkkk. Agora percebo porquê não obrigar as pessoas a aceitarem as respostas.

Comment: Sobre a espera, ver também http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/ @Cold

Comment: @Cold, eu acho estranho quando alguém aceita sem +1. Agradecer quem respondeu é com +1, o comentário é opcional. Avisar pro mundo que aquela resposta resolve o problema é o com o aceite. O tempo pra fazer isso, sigo mais ou menos o mesmo procedimento dos colegas.

Comment: Pois, mas pra ser sincero (se calhar  é por nao ter lido a documentação de forma apropriada) a sensação que possuo qunato ao +1 é que não pra o AP mas pra "outros" que achem de facto a solução brilhante ou aquela que resolve o problema, e em vez de re-responderem simplesmente apoiam(ou concordam) com a solução boa. Não percebo de forma intuitiva que o +1 é agradecimento. Indicar que a resposta está certa parece-me ser, intuitivamente, a forma de agradecimento.

Comment: @Cold Várias respostas podem estar certas, mas somente uma pode ser escolhida como "a melhor". E aí, como agradecer a todos? ;)

Comment: Yah, aí sim. Porém já requer um pouco mais de raciocínio. Eu falava de intuitividade(só pra não dizer que quando todo mundo ajuda e todas opções funcionam dá vontade de "aceitar" todas as respostas :)). Já agora qual mesmo a documentação descrevendo isso? kkkk

Comment: **Documentação oficial:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. **Documentação da comunidade:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas. @Cold

Comment: Eu costumo esperar dias para indicar a resposta correta.